# WCF customization to work with OAuth & JWT's

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

We're architecting a new commercial application.  We're layering everything and in the middle tier our CRUD & business workflows will be in their own assemblies.  This will allow us to use both WCF & Web Api's to allow consumers to interface with our data backend.

For our MVC UI, web service to web service, windows service to web services calls, we plan to use WCF with custom, Net.TCP or Named Pipe bindings as the case my be.

However, we also want to create Web Api interfaces as we need them in the future.  There may be times in our MVC applications where we have a specific need to may javascript service calls.

But mainly we want an avenue down the road should we need to support mobile devices interfacing with our back end.

Here is a mspaint diagram of what we're planning.

[image: Application Architeture]

We plan to stick with mostly server side code first and only resort to javascript when absolutely necessary.

We plan to favor WCF & the most efficient form of binary serialization we can fit versus Web Api where possible.

With that, we're trying to come up with a Authentication & Authorization architecture we can use with all different layers our application.

Originally I was hoping to use something like DotNetOAuth or Thinktecture IdentityServer 3 to authenticate and hopeful generate token based claims.  It seems that if we could figure out how to create support in WCF for JSon Web Tokens, that would be the most flexible.

We plan to try and use Microsoft's Identity and Claims.

With that, is it possible with custom code to customize WCF to be able to use a solution like Thinktecture to authenticate and use tokens for claims based authorization?  If so is there any documentation/samples out there we're missing.

To be clear, a user authenticates from our MVC UI apps to IdentityServer3 or equivalent, gets a JWT claims token.  A call is made to a WCF service or WebApi and they both can use verify the claim and use it for authorization?

Or are we going to have to resort to something like WIF, create a custom STS and then have an OAuth service in parallel?

2/26/15 - Last night I found the following post.  http://www.thecoderblogs.com/2014/04/exercise-3-securing-a-wcf-service-using-windows-azure-active-directory/  It looks promising, however, the sample link doesn't work.  Need to figure out how to populate the WCF client with header with Authorize and the token.  Again any input would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Both would work  - either have a WS-Trust endpoint connected to the same user database - or make WCF consume JWT tokens. Both require some custom coding.

Comment: Thanks lp.  I've spent the last couple of weeks getting Identity Server v3 set, integrating it into our client MVC apps and then the Web Api interface to our backend.  I'm using the Hybrid MVC sample from Identity samples.

Comment: I think trying to figure out how to get WCF to consume JWT tokens would be the way to go with my limited knowledge at this point.  Any points on how to go about creating custom code for WCF to consume JWT's?  Just about all my searches involve WCF Web Api.  Any pointers of how to do this with native WCF bindings would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I used information from several different places and we're using a custom IDispatchMessageInspector.

I created a 3 part blog series on what we did to accomplish this which can be found [here](https://kkfrost.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/identity-server-v3-setup/).

We still need to figure out a way to authenticate/authorize an AccessToken returned by IdentityServices TokenResponse when making a call to RequestClientCredentialAsync().

Please if you review the log, leave comments if you have any improvements or have anything to add.